# Proliant ML10 gen9 SSD upgrade

Tags: windows, backup, storage, ssd, cloning

I have a proliant ML10 gen9 with windows server 2012 r2 foundation installed.

The system has a software raid 1 setup (intel rst) with two 1tb HP sata hdds and has started to run very slow.

I am considering upgrading with two ssd disks (samsung PM893 960gb) but I am a little confused with the options to clone or transfer the OS. Reinstalling OS is my very last option and should be avoided.

First option is to shrink the original volume (availalbe shrink size is narrow, around 50gb), create windows backup image, remove the current disks, install the ssd disks, create a raid 1 array, boot from media, proceed with recovery.

My question is, if something goes wrong during recovery,will reseating the original disks work again ? Is raid configuration stored in the disks (like I think is the case with hardware raid like P400s) ?

Or should I just install the new ssds, create a second array and use a third party software to hot clone the OS ?

I can't afford to lose the current working installation as reinstalling everything would cause trouble. And I don't totally trust the bare metal backup.

I also do not like the idea of recreating the array by replacing the drives one by one with ssds.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Whatever you do, always have a good, tested backup at hand.